# What Chaining Mode to use with RSA? (CNG's BCrypt)

Tags: rsa

I'm trying to make my first RSA encryption/decryption using CNG. In 1 part of the example they add pick a chaining mode, I don't know if this is mandatory and when I tried to google about it I found that most of those are not safe. So I would like to know which one is the right one to pick.
(In the future I would like to use it to sign data)

From [Cryptography Primitive Property Identifiers, Microsoft's Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/seccng/cng-property-identifiers) it offers:

- CBC
- CCM
- CFB
- ECB
- GCM

Comment: Are you trying to implement encryption with RSA or are you trying to implement hybrid encryption?

Comment: Hello I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a simple string like "Hello World" with a key pair to learn about it. Then I'm trying to use it to sign data and if I didn't misunderstand what I read online then hybrid encryption is the best way to do it. So I would say both.

Comment: All may depend on your aim. Why do you need encryption and what are your attack model

Comment: I need encryption to sign data sent from my desktop app to my api. I need to know that this data was not modified and that it was sent by the desktop app. I'm not familiar with the term "attack model", sorry.

Comment: For example, How do you generate your AES key from your password?  where are the keys stored? Do you assume that your desktop can be attacked? Where is the API is stored? etc.. lots of question needs to be clarified.

Comment: Could you please point out the example? There might be a confusion on what to apply the chaining mode for. Generally RSA is not chained and you'd use `BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_NA`. However, without the example code I cannot tell if that's correct as an answer.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. There is no code, I'm trying to write my first asymmetric encryption/decryption code using CNG. 1 key is stored in my cloud hosting (my api will use it to decrypt the information), the other key is stored in my desktop app (my desktop app will use it to encrypt the information). I don't mind about if I can be attacked or such atm. First I want to do a simple code and see how it works but I'm stuck because I don't know what chaining I need to choose.

Comment: It is correct to use RSA without a chain mode? Like security wise.